# Issue Using tensorflow hub Universal Sentence Encoder with local runtime and GPU in Google Colab

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory, anaconda3, tensorflow-hub

I am working through a machine learning course to learn tensorflow. In one of the project I was performing text classification using a tensorflow_hub pre trained embedding, the Universal sentence encoder v4. The embeddings worked fine using the google Colab GPU, and also worked in my local runtime without my GPU. However, after I set up colab to be able to use my local GPU (RTX 3060), I started getting the error seen below. For reference, my python environment is through Anaconda, and I used conda install to install tensorflow_gpu and cudatoolkit and cudnn. I am not sure what this error means or how to even begin debugging it, any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Code and error:

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub
tf_hub_embedding = hub.KerasLayer('https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4',trainable=False,name='USE')

rand_sent = random.choice(train_sents)
print(f'Random sent: {rand_sent}\n')
print(f'Embedded sent: {tf_hub_embedding([rand_sent])[0][:30]}\n')
print(f'Embed length: {len(tf_hub_embedding([rand_sent])[0])}')

Random sent: Data of a Japanese study of patients with unresectable sacral chordoma showed comparable high control rates after hypofractionated carbon ion therapy only .

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnknownError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [55], in <cell line: 3>()
      1 rand_sent = random.choice(train_sents)
      2 print(f'Random sent: {rand_sent}\n')
----> 3 print(f'Embedded sent: {tf_hub_embedding([rand_sent])[0][:30]}\n')
      4 print(f'Embed length: {len(tf_hub_embedding([rand_sent])[0])}')

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py:67, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     65 except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
     66   filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
---> 67   raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     68 finally:
     69   del filtered_tb

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_hub\keras_layer.py:229, in KerasLayer.call(self, inputs, training)
    223 # ...but we may also have to pass a Python boolean for `training`, which
    224 # is the logical "and" of this layer's trainability and what the surrounding
    225 # model is doing (analogous to tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization in TF2).
    226 # For the latter, we have to look in two places: the `training` argument,
    227 # or else Keras' global `learning_phase`, which might actually be a tensor.
    228 if not self._has_training_argument:
--> 229   result = f()
    230 else:
    231   if self.trainable:

UnknownError: Exception encountered when calling layer "USE" (type KerasLayer).

Graph execution error:

JIT compilation failed.
     [[{{node EncoderDNN/EmbeddingLookup/EmbeddingLookupUnique/embedding_lookup/mod}}]] [Op:__inference_restored_function_body_36706]

Call arguments received by layer "USE" (type KerasLayer):
  • inputs=["'Data of a Japanese study of patients with unresectable sacral chordoma showed comparable high control rates after hypofractionated carbon ion therapy only .'"]
  • training=None
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue, and I solve it by downgrading my TensorFlow version to 2.8.0.

Using this command

```
pip install tensorflow==2.8.0
```